# How to resume an activity when calling it from an Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have the following situation: one activity (DateActivity) calls another activity (ListActivity) when a button is clicked. That is working. However, every time the button is clicked it seems that a new copy of ListActivity is created. How do I make it resume the last ListActivity or create a new one if needed?

Note: I'm currently starting the ListActivity using `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: try this instead

[Saving Activity state in Android][1]

Hope this is helpful


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

not quite sure about your situation, but you can use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); startActivity(intent);` to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the flag for the intent you are using.

```
Inten Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
//this is what you are looking for
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

There are a lot of constants for the Intent object, for more information check the hint on your IDE when you star typing "FLAG_"

Answer (score -2):

Use `startActivityForActivity()` to launch ListActivity and use `setResult()` to return an Intent containing the state you want to return to next time. In DataActivity, `onActivityResult()` will receive this intent returned from ListActivity. The next time you launch ListActivity pass this (well traveled) intent to "resume" where you left off.